# jQuery script doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

I took the following code from [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423671/jquery-click-off-element-event) here on StackOverflow:

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#myDiv').length) {
        $('#myDiv').hide();
    };
});
```

The only problem is that on Firefox (on Safari works) doesn't work. Why is that?
How should I change it to make it compatible with Firefox?

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Does the event not fire? Or does the selector not find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old trick copied from [Which HTML element is the target of the event?](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

```
$(function() {
    $('body').click(function(event) {

        var targ;
        if (event.target) targ = event.target;
        else if (event.srcElement) targ = event.srcElement;
        if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
           targ = targ.parentNode;

        if (!$(targ).closest('#myDiv').length) {
            $('#myDiv').hide();
        };
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/MGQj5/) 
Clicking outside the div will hied the div `!$(targ).closest('#myDiv').length`

Comment: It works on the demo but on my website it doesn't work. I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 with the jQuery UI 1.8.16. The only thing different from that code is that before I set `$("#myDiv").draggable();`. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it did not worked

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    target = (window.event) ? window.event.srcElement /* for IE */ : event.target;
    if (!($(target).closest('#myDiv').length>0)) {
        $('#myDiv').hide();
    };
});
```